# What is the Auto-Alignment Shortcut Key in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, alignment, eclipse-3.4

What is the auto-alignment shortcut key in Eclipse?

Answer (score 318, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to invoke the Auto Formatter

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to indent the selected part (or all) of you code.

Comment: I was hoping for something that would align = signs across several lines of assignment statements. :(

Comment: hi Peter thank you for sharing information this is useful for edit format document file ..

Comment: I wonder why they put "CTRL + ALT + L (Win)" as the answer out there....  http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html#KeyCommands

Comment: @DavidJames: for aligning on a special character or string, see [djeikyb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20432333/1498405) for the plugin [Columns4Eclipse](http://columns4eclipse.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: `Cmd`+`I` on Mac respectively

Comment: In my case in MAC, it is: cmd + Shift + F

Comment: On Mac : ⌘ + ⇧ + F

Answer (score 36):

Auto-alignment? Lawful good?

If you mean formatting, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Answer (score 18):

The answer that the OP accepted is wildly different from the question I thought was asked. I thought the OP wanted a way to auto-align `=` signs or `+` signs, similar to the tabularize plugin for vim.

For *this* task, I found the [Columns4Eclipse](http://columns4eclipse.sourceforge.net/) plugin to be just what I needed.

Comment: An under-rated answer!

Answer (score 13):

Want to format it automatically when you save the file???

then Goto
Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions

and configure your save actions.

Along with saving, 
you can format, Organize imports,add modifier ‘final’ where possible etc

Comment: Can I work with one formatter profile and save with another formatter.

Answer (score 0):

auto-alignment shortcut key `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F`

to change the shortcut keys Goto Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions