# Align code using tab in VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, coding-style

This might be a personal preference, but I'm bit used to do this kind of aligning using tabs

```
        Application excelApplication    = null;
        Workbooks workBooks             = null;
        Workbook activeWorkBook         = null;
        Worksheet activeWorkSheet       = null;
```

Is there anyway I can get it done automatically using some key combinations? At the moment I do align/indent using tabs manually. I know Ctrl K + Ctrl F exists, but it does't give the above alignment/indentation.

Any plugins/ formatting tips are highly appreciated. I also use Resharper, is there a setting in Resharper which can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ReSharper formatting: align equal operands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286806/resharper-formatting-align-equal-operands)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go here and download the 'Productivity'Tools for VS2010: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

Scroll down to the paragraph Align Assignments, it does what you want.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but do you know of any equivalent for Eclipse?

Comment: @Nullable looks like it doesn't work over several lines of code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378258/what-is-the-auto-alignment-shortcut-key-in-eclipse

Comment: It also doesn't appear to use tabs, only spaces, which causes issues for some people.

Answer (score 0):

**[CodeAlignment](http://www.codealignment.com/)** - MUCH better than Productivity Tools. CodeAlignment can align on just about any character while Productivity Tools can only do "="

And I discovered that CA is smart about code blocks. Without highlighting anything CA will align an entire code block - put the cursor on any line and it affects all lines above and below that line until it gets to a blank line. Alternatively you can select the desired lines first.